# Calculate count of permutations in array without repetition by Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

First I have an array, like this:

```
var arr = [[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
           [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

It is not necessarily should be this array, it could be any other, it is just example. So I need to know the count of all possible permutations, something like this:

```
2,3,4
2,3,5
...
2,3,12

2,4,5
2,4,6
...
2,4,12

...
10,11,12
```

It is not simple permutations, as I understand. And also I don't need all this combination, I just need their count, may be exist formula or something like this. In this example I know that answer is 165. Thank you

Comment: You don't seem to be describing permutations. Simply a selection of a single element from each array. No?

There are 9 objects to select from in each array so there are 729 possible combinations

Comment: I think you mean select 1 item from each array without a repeated number in the selection, e.g. 2,4,4 is not valid.

Comment: You also seem to have the constraint that the resulting array must be in ascending order. Otherwise you won't get 165 possible results. Could you please describe more clearly what the constraints on the input and output are?

Comment: @MOehm, it's still 405

Comment: What is the actual task you're trying to solve? Those arrays seem to have a quite simple structure, how did you generate them? Probably there's a much easier formula that uses the parameters of your problem, instead of some arrays.

Comment: It never was *permutations* anyway, you are looking for the [*cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (without duplicates)

Comment: @MOehm, Actually it is 165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the order must increase:

```
var arr = [[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
           [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
           [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]];

function count(stack, history) {
  var counter = 0;
  history = history || [];
  stack[0].forEach(function(it) {
    if (! history.length || history[history.length -1] < it) {
      if (stack[1]) {
        counter += count(stack.slice(1), history.concat([it]));
      } else  {
        counter++;
      }
    }
  });
  return counter;
}

console.log(count(arr)); //165
```

Comment: Correct, but duplicate numbers are not allowed, that is why it is not simple permutations)

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting mathematical problem. I think what you are referring to is combinations and not permutations. I place the javascript here first. The math follows below that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = new Array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
arr[1] = new Array(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
arr[2] = new Array(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);


function countcombinations() {
    var history = new Array();

    for (var i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<arr[1].length;j++) {  
            for (var k=0;k<arr[2].length;k++) {
                if (arr[0][i] == arr[1][j] || arr[0][i] == arr[2][k] || arr[1][j] == arr[2][k]) {
                } else {
                    // If all are different, consider this set as candidate
                    var found = false;

                    history.forEach(function(entry) {
                        if (
                            // The various possible sequences for comparison
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[0] && arr[1][j] == entry[1] && arr[2][k] == entry[2]) ||
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[0] && arr[1][j] == entry[2] && arr[2][k] == entry[1]) ||
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[1] && arr[1][j] == entry[0] && arr[2][k] == entry[2]) ||
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[1] && arr[1][j] == entry[2] && arr[2][k] == entry[0]) ||
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[2] && arr[1][j] == entry[0] && arr[2][k] == entry[1]) ||
                            (arr[0][i] == entry[2] && arr[1][j] == entry[1] && arr[2][k] == entry[0])
                        ) found = true;
                    });

                    // If not found, add to history
                    if (!found) history[history.length] = new Array(arr[0][i], arr[1][j], arr[2][k]);                   
                }
            }
        }
    }  

    alert ("Count: " + history.length);
}

countcombinations(); // Gives 165

</script>
```

Mathematically, the problem can be solved by iterating the first set and considering the possibilities for each. This is what the algorithm in the above javascript code does. The sequence of the elements do not matter. Each time a new unique combination is found, it appends this combination to the history. For fun, you could experiment with the above code and apply the math below to understand it further.

For a human approach to the math, let's consider the first set and use (X, Y, Z) to denote the three chosen numbers. The numbers in each set need to be in increasing order and the smallest number in subsequent sets also need to be in increasing order. The array given to us meets these conditions. So, for the first set:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

When X = 2, i.e., (2, Y, Z), there are two possibilities to consider:

```
Y = 3
Y > 3
```

If Y = 3, then Z has 9 possibilities (4 through to 12).

If Y > 3, then if Z < 12, (Y, Z) has 8C2 (8 choose 2), or 28, possible combinations. 
If Z = 12, then (Y, 12) has 8 possible combinations. Thus:

```
X = 2, Y = 3, Z > 3 : 9 combinations
X = 2, Y > 3, Z < 12 : 8C2 = 28 combinations
X = 2, Y > 3, Z = 12 : 8 combinations
In short, there are 45 possible combinations where any of the numbers is 2.
```

Phew! Moving on, from numbers 3 to 9, you can reuse two conditions above: whether Z < 12 or Z = 12.  You will see a pattern emerging as shown below:

```
X = 3, Y > 3, Z < 12: 8C2 = 28 combinations
X = 3, Y > 3, Z = 12: 8 combinations

X = 4, Y > 4, Z < 12: 7C2 = 21 combinations
X = 4, Y > 4, Z < 12: 7 combinations

...

X = 9, Y > 9, Z < 12: 2C2 = 1  combination
X = 9, Y > 9, Z = 12: 2 combinations
```

Finally, when X = 10, there is only 1 possibility that is (10, 11, 12).

Thus the number of combinations (with a nice decreasing pattern) is:

```
X = 2: 9 + 8C2 + 8 = 45
X = 3: 8C2 + 8 = 36
X = 4: 7C2 + 7 = 28
X = 5: 6C2 + 6 = 21
X = 6: 5C2 + 5 = 15
X = 7: 4C2 + 4 = 10
X = 8: 3C2 + 3 = 6
X = 9: 2C2 + 2 = 3
X = 10: 1 = 1
TOTAL: 165
```